# Condensing Code for GET Variables That Return The Same Values

Tags: php, minify

I'm going to be placing identical content for different URL strings, so I want to condense the code somehow.  Heres the Code

```
if($_GET['name']=='1'){
    $section = "Box 1";
}
if($_GET['name']=='2'){
    $section = "Box 1";
}
if($_GET['name']=='3'){
    $section = "Box 1";
}
if($_GET['name']=='4'){
    $section = "Box 1";
}
```

I tried this, but with no luck:

```
if($_GET['name']=='1','2','3','4'){
    $section = "Box 1";
}
```

How do I condense the code so I don't repeat the same thing over and over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( in_array($_GET['name'], array(1,2,3,4)) ) {
  $selection = 'Box 1';
}
```

I think it should helps.

Comment: If yes, just do this in_array((int)$_GET['name'], array(1,2,3,4))

Comment: @wizard pasting this code exactly like above, im getting: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' ` but i dont understand what could be causing it.  also getting the same error when checking on phpcodechecker.com

Comment: I've just answer on the question, here is no option to check arguments. Of course all that you receive from client should be validated and sanitized. :) sry..

Comment: oh.. fixed that.. just miss one closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = intval($_GET['name']);

if($val >= 1 && $val <= 4 ){
    $section = 'Box 1';
}
```